# Typescript - method that takes a key and a new value

Tags: typescript

I want to create a function that takes two parameters, a key and a value, but I can't do it with typescript. Perhaps this is a duplicate question, then direct me to the original question, on my own I could not find the answer

```
interface SomeObject {
  key1: string;
  key2: number;
  key3: boolean;
}

class SomeClass {
  public fields: {
    [field in keyof SomeObject]: SomeObject[field];
  };

  constructor() {
    this.fields = {
      key1: "",
      key2: 123,
      key3: false,
    };
  }

  setValue = (
    key: keyof SomeObject,
    value: SomeObject[keyof SomeObject],
  ): void => {
    this.fields[key] = value;
  };
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's currently nothing tying your `key` and `value` arguments together. I assume, for example, that if `'key1'` is passed as the key, then the type of `value` should be `string`?

You can achieve this linked type functionality using generics:

```
setValue<T extends keyof SomeObject>(
    key: T,
    value: SomeObject[T],
): void {
    this.fields[key] = value;
}
```